# One ID with many values

Tags: html, database

This is my table in database.

```
+-------+------------+
|    ID |    VALUES  |
+-------+------------+
|    1  |   mon      |
|    1  |   tues     |
|    1  |   wed      |
|    2  |   mon      |
|    2  |   tues     |
|    2  |   wed      |
|    3  |   mon      |
|    3  |   tues     |
|    3  |   wed      |         
+-------+------------+
```

and this is what I want my table  to look like in client-server.

```
+-------+------------+
|    ID |    DAYS    |
+-------+------------+
|    1  |mon tues wed|
|    2  |mon tues wed|
|    3  |mon tues wed|
+-------+------------+
```

guys any idea? what would be the SQL query code?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thats not a good implementation..just my opinion. Have columns for your days and an auto increment column for your id. These columns could be bit or ints... Then you can query of the id for the days... Also what DBMS you using?

Comment: Which Database you are using?

Comment: @Anuraj I'm using SQL to be exact mySQL.

Comment: You still haven't clarified the question you're asking. What are you trying to do? It's not clear from the screenshots what the implementation here is.

Comment: someone got it. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clear how you'll be using this, but you could concat the days grouped by ID.

```
// Get the data
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT( DAYS ORDER BY ID SEPARATOR ' ') AS DAYS FROM table
```

Will produce the results you mentioned, but I'm not sure how real-world useful this is.

Comment: this worked. thanks for the help although my instruction was not clear. :)